# TypeError: must be str, not int; Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've been trying to write a code for Fibonacci using memorization on Python.

Here's my code

```
def fib(n, memo):
    if memo[n] is not None:
        return memo[n]
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = fib_2(n-1, memo) + fib_2(n-2, memo)

memo[n] = result
return result

def fib_memo(n):
    memo = [None] * (n + 1)
    return fib(n, memo)

t = input("number ")

print(fib_memo(t))
```

It returns:-

> TypeError: must be str, not int" on line 17- memo = [None] * (n + 1)

I can't seem to understand the issue here.

Comment: you need to use  this `t  = int(input("number"))` or `print(fib_memo(int(t)))`. Because, keyboard input using `input()` are by default string.

Comment: Input returns a string, not an integer. You need to do `t = int(input("..."))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this `t = int(input("number"))` or `print(fib_memo(int(t)))`. Because, keyboard input using `input()` are by default string.

Here's your complete working code:-

```
def fib(n, memo):
    if memo[n] is not None:
        return memo[n]
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = fib(n-1, memo) + fib(n-2, memo)

    memo[n] = result
    return result

def fib_memo(n):
    memo = [None] * (n + 1)
    return fib(n, memo)

t = input("number ")

print(fib_memo(int(t)))
```